# Load simple in stock Skus on configurable produdct view magento

Tags: magento, get, product

need to get simple in stock sku associated to configurable product in ascending order on product view page.

```
Result like:

[1] = "S120622006_5";
[2] = "S120622007";
[4] = "S120622008";
[5] = "S120622009";
[6] = "S1206220010";
```

My start scipt: this get all sku for associated on configurable, but this get the result not arranged and show the out of stock sku. I want to get only the In stock sku and on ascending order.

```
<?php
    $conf = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($_product);
    $col = $conf->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFilterByRequiredOptions();
?>

<?php
    $count = 1;
    $itemId = array();
    foreach($col as $simple_product){
        $itemId[] = array($simple_product->getSelectLabel() => $simple_product->getSku());
    }

    foreach($itemId as $val){
        foreach($val as $k => $v){
            echo 'Skus['.$count.'] = "'.$v.'";'. "\n";
            $count++;
        }
    };
?>
```

I appreciate any help.

Result from R.S

```
S1206220010_5 = 
S1206220011_5 = 
S1206220012_5 = 
S120622006_5 = 
S120622007 = 
S120622007_5 = 
S120622008 = 
S120622008_5 = 
S120622009_5 = 
S120622009 = 
S1206220010 = 
S1206220011 =
```

Comment: i will appreciate any other help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can't test right now but try this:

`->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('qty', array('gteq' => 1))`